# SwiftUI - Random word animation with letters scrolling

Tags: xcode, animation, random, swiftui, rotation

I would like to implement a random word generator, shaped similar as to a [Cryptex](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51N8kVzTv8L._AC_.jpg). I would like to have the single letters that rotate in a "wheel picker style" (as if the system was going through all the letters of the alphabet to pick the right ones) and that one at a time they'd stop to reveal the word.

I have implemented a string that gets randomized, with the single letters that all have individual 3d rotation animation. However, I have no idea on how to go from here to the result I'd like to have. In the code listed here below there's also a function that I created to generate the delay, so each letter could animate a bit longer. I tried adding this func to the duration value of the Animation, but with that the animation stops working. I left the func anyway, in case it might be useful.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var degrees = 0.0
    var words = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"]
    @State var text = "???"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(Array(text), id: \.self) { letters in
                    Text(String(letters))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(degrees), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
                        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 3).speed(10), value: degrees)
                    
                }
            }
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    self.degrees += 720
                    let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0...(words.count-1))
                    text = words[randomIndex]
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Get a random word!")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .padding(.top, 40)
        }
    }
    
    func generateDelay(letter: String.Element) -> Double {
        let delayFromIndex : Double = Double(Array(text).firstIndex(where: { $0 == letter }) ?? 0)
        let delay : Double = 3 + delayFromIndex
        return delay
    }
}

extension ForEach where Data.Element: Hashable, ID == Data.Element, Content: View {
    init(values: Data, content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content) {
        self.init(values, id: \.self, content: content)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: It would seem to me that you don't need your word necessarily randomized, you need to have arrays of letters that cycle through in order, but maybe starting at random places and going through multiple rotations, that eventually stop on the correct letter. Therefore, you would need to make one of these arrays per letter of your word and rotate through the arrays.

Comment: @Yrb thanks for your reply. How would I cycle through letter and then stop at the correct one for each position?

Comment: I would think you could work out a random number of cycles that on the last cycle simply stops at the correct letter. I haven't done it, and the algorithm isn't jumping out at me. Google may be your best friend here, as it isn't a Swift or SwiftUI problem, but more of a straight algorithmic one. If you put together a solution, post it as the answer.